# Can I name my app using the name of a long defunct company?

Tags: trademark

I am working on an app and want to name it Vidmark. Apparently, this name is the name of a long-defunct company (since 2001). Could I get into trouble using this name?

Comment: 2001 is *long*-defunct?

Comment: @FakeName 2001 is older than this year's university freshmen.

Comment: I'm stealing your name.  I'm going to use it for a brand of hybrid soybean. It'll soon be the talk of farm shows.  There'll be little signs "Vidmark 4031" or whatever at the end of cornrows on demonstration farms.   Somehow I don't think there'll be a naming conflict.

Comment: @FakeName How is it not? In business, 19 years is a long time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is almost assuredly, no, you can't use it.

Vidmark was parented as Trimark Holdings which was bought by Lionsgate in 2001. Lionsgate is still very much an active company, and has been using the Vidmark name as lately as 2017 when it released a Roku streaming channel under the "Vidmark" name.

So Lionsgate is the holder of this particular trademark, and is actively using it.

[TESS shows that the trademark is still Live](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4808:9kv2l0.2.1) and was re-registered in 2017.

Comment: I see, thank you.
Would it be possible to use some kind of title with the name Vidmark in it?
Something along the lines of "Vidmark It", etc.

Comment: I wouldn't push it in that regard, especially if your app has something to do with video. If it's completely unrelated to it, it may be OK but you'll have to try to submit a trademark application to see if it's rejected as "too similar" or in a related field.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much!

Comment: Just to make this clear: The fact that Vidmark is the name of a defunct company does not really matter here - what matters is that "Vidmark" is a **trademark**. In practice, company names are often registered as trademarks, too, but not always.

Comment: Doesn't it also depend on the **field** the company is involved is? For example, if you develop a new computer or phone, you are not allowed to call it "Apple", or write "Apple" on it, but if you manufacture soft drinks which taste like apple, or bake fruitcakes etc. you are pretty surely allowed to use it.

Comment: @vsz Read my comment below the question... Yes, it does, somewhat, Vidmark is both a trademark and a brand so the OP can try to register a similar trademark in a completely unrelated field, however Lionsgate developed an "app" for Roku using the name, so it's unlikely that they would be OK with somebody using the name for another app, even if it's a different app store.

Comment: @vsz, I would still be careful with Apple, even though they lost this one: https://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/markenstreit-cafe-apfelkind-besiegt-apple-1.1784653

Comment: @RonBeyer Do you think I could use Vidmarker as the name for the app? Is that somehow pushing it? The app has to do with YouTube if that matters.